# Не понятна работа Handler & Looper

Tags: android, многопоточность, очередь, android-handler

Сколько я не читал примеров, не смотрел лекций и теоретических объяснений класса `Handler` - мне не понятно как практически с ним работать.

Теоретически - это класс, который управляет некой очередью, называемой `Looper` , которая оперирует некими сообщениями, которые передает `Handler`. Так же сам `Handler` способен обрабатывать эти сообщения.
Вроде бы идея в том, чтобы дать UI потоку выполнять эти сообщения порциями, которые не будут его затормаживать, и мешать прорисовке.

Но я совершенно не понимаю, что это за сообщения, как и куда их передавать - примеры не очевидны.

Можете написать маленький курс по этой "иллюзии" многопоточности, с примерами для простых типов и классов?(Возможно сказал глупость, но в моем представлении, в этом сообщении можно передавать ссылку на объект или какое-либо сообщение).

Просьба на сайт Александра Климова\СтартАндроид\офф. документацию не отправлять, уже не раз там бывал. Так же изучал лекции технопарка.

Comment: Вот неплохая статья: https://habrahabr.ru/post/142256/ А мне вот не очень понятны ваши цели: практические или академические? Практические - а в чем сложности, копипастишь код по мануалу и все. Есть проблемы - спрашивайте конкретно по коду. Академические... простите, но вопрос выдает то, что вы с трудом понимаете Java, ООП и работу ОС Android. Может стоит вернуться к этому вопросу позже, когда будет достаточно понимания основных принципов? Я сомневаюсь, что здесь кто-то сможет тягаться по стилю изложения со всеми приведенными вами источниками одновременно.